# Error :when deploying a pod image pull back off error in gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

What is the reason of this error?

How to fix this above error?

I try to resolve this error but getting same error again and again

I'm new to kubernetes so I need your help

Error :when deploying a pod image pull back off error in gke

Comment: "The name you specified in `image:` doesn't exist on the node where it's being run, and it can't be fetched from Docker Hub or the registry named in the image name."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  David Maze  mentioned  "The name you specified in image: doesn't exist on the node where it's being run, and it can't be fetched from Docker Hub or the registry named in the image name”

As per this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#ImagePullBackOff), ImagePullBackOff error indicates that the image used by a container cannot be loaded from the image registry.

Network connectivity issues, an incorrect image name or tag, missing credentials, or insufficient permissions are all possible causes of this error.

> You can verify this issue using the Google Cloud console or the
> kubectl command-line tool.
>
> ```
> kubectl describe pod
> ```
>
> **If you encounter the image is not found**:
>
> You need to follow this [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#if_the_image_is_not_found) steps to resolve your
> issue
>
> **If you get Permission denied error**:
>
> If you encounter a "permission denied" or "no pull access" error,
> verify that you are logged in and have access to the image. Try one of
> the following [methods](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#permission_denied_error) depending on the registry in which you host
> your images.

Comment: If the issue still  persists then edit the question  with exact error you are getting